# Conditional Split in SSIS based on the number of times a character appears in a string

Tags: sql, ssis

I would like to split the flow of data based on the number of times a particular character appears in a string.

```
Source Data:  
R1 - 123@abc.com  
R2 - 567@stu.com  
R3 - 234@fgh.com,456@xyz.com  
R4 - 567@wxy.com,789@pqr.com  
R5 - 678@def.com
```

As seen above, 2 of the four records contain the "@" symbol twice. I want to split data based on the number of times this character appears in a line

```
Expected result  
Flat_File_Once (3 rows)  
R1 - 123@abc.com  
R2 - 567@stu.com  
R3 - 678@def.com  

Flat_File_Twice (2 rows)  
R1 - 234@fgh.com,456@xyz.com  
R2 - 567@wxy.com,789@pqr.com
```

This works in SQL, not sure how to do it in SSIS

```
 len(email) - len(replace(email, '@', '')) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's virtually the same formula except we'll use double quotes instead of single quotes

```
LEN([email]) - LEN(REPLACE([email], "@", ""))
```

That expression generates the total number of instances of the @ character. Clever approach, I probably would have gotten bogged down trying to use `FINDSTRING`